# matlab plot data over an image

Tags: image, matlab, plot, overlay

I would like to plot a scatter plot over a background image. But the origin of the image is at the top left corner. I need the bottom left of the image to be the origin so the bottom left = (0, 0.75) and top right (14, 1.25)

So I need to scale the image to my data from pH 0 - 14 (This is the x axis) and Eh 0.75 - 1.25 (This is the y axis)

[image: Image used in code]

```
Eh = [327.06 561.34 506.82 602.58 745.02 745.04 ...
    693.96 682.9 648.46 468 412.18 522.94 459.74]./1e3; % V
pH = [6.4 4.51 5.08 4.98 3.63 4.31 6.24 6.22 4.94 6.44 7.05 5.09 4.63]; %pH

I=imread('Fe_Pourbaix.png');

xImg = linspace(0, 14, size(I, 2));
yImg = linspace(-0.75, 1.25, size(I, 1));

image(xImg, yImg, I, 'CDataMapping', 'scale');

hold on;
plot(pH, Eh,'*','LineWidth',2);
grid on;
```

Suppose I Need to flip the data? The below image is what I need is the x and y I need to produce to overlay my data

[image: The axis I need]

Comment: Yes, flipping sounds right. Everything else kept equal, probably `image(xImg, -yImg, flip(I,1), 'CDataMapping', 'scale');`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have edit my post above to include what I want to produce. I'm still trying to play around with image flipping.

Comment: You might read up on the options for the `axis` command: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#buk989s-1-ydirection

Comment: Ah! So reversing the values (using `yImg` or `yImg(end:-1:1)`) does not make a difference, it will still display the values from top to bottom. I never knew that... So in this case, you first plot the flipped image with the original `yImg` (see my previous comment without the `-`) and then do `axis xy`. Does not look logical but it seems to work.